# Managing access to several identical resources using semaphores

Tags: c#

I need to come up with a "ResourceManager" C# class that will create "n" threads (one for HW resource) and hand them to clients so they can use it. Each client is running on a separate thread and will make a blocking call like 
Resource resource = ResourceManager.GetResource() 
If there are no available resources after certain timeOut, it'll throw an exception.
The caller then will release the resource when it's done.

I am thinking of using an array of Semaphores(size n) controlling an array on Resources[n]
and using them to signal whether the resource is available or not, with the client signaling the semaphore when calling the server Release method, but I have the feeling that it's not the simplest design.

Are there any references/resources that have information about resource management on multi-threaded applications?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you using .NET 4, or earlier?  (It makes a difference here...)